# WebDav returns error 405 on IIS 7.5 and OS Win2k8

Tags: iis-7.5, webdav

I have configured a WebDav application on IIS 7.5 with OS Win2k8.
I created a local user of Server machine.
But When i try to upload a file using my WebDav application it gives me error 405.
I set webdav authroing rules Read,Source,Write. Authentication is Winodows, directory browsing is enabled. All content are accessible to all users.

What might be miss from my configuration?
Do any one have clue?

Thanks

Asif

Comment: Almost impossible to say without you actually posting your configuration, please provide more information.

Comment: Same problem. followed all the setup steps here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis/